# ParseFile.cancel() not working - file keeps being downloaded

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using `parse.com` Android SDK to manage some images in my app. Is `cancel()` the only way to stop a transaction with the `parse.com` server?

Minimal example:

```
final ParseFile file = ... ;
file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

    //called when loading is done
    @Override
    public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(bytes == null));
    }

}, new ProgressCallback() {

    //called to notify progress   
    @Override
    public void done(Integer integer) {
        Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(integer));
        if (integer > 50) {
            file.cancel();
        }
    }
});
```

I would expect that loading stops after the 50% is reached, but it does not. My log in this situation would be:

```
1
2
3
....
49
50
51
....
98
99
100
true
```

The only difference from times you call `cancel()` and times you don't, is that if you canceled the `byte[]` result is null. But that is really secondary, the point here is that `file` keeps consuming bandwidth and, moreover, overlaps with future downloads, slowing things down.

Is there any way to *really* stop ParseFile loading? Do you see any workaround, like stopping its thread? Maybe something using the underlying bolts framework? Using my own async task?

Example: [`continueWhile()`](http://boltsframework.github.io/docs/android/bolts/Task.html#continueWhile(java.util.concurrent.Callable,%20bolts.Continuation,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor)) method might be useful, but I can't figure out how to use it.

---

I would like to know the reason for the downvote, maybe the common title? That is really what I am experiencing: ParseFile.cancel() *is not working*. And it should, according to the official [docs](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseFile.html#cancel()).

Comments suggest that I should simply call `break`. While I don't think it would work, I might clarify that the code I posted was just a minimal, concise working example providing both context and the issue. I don't want to `cancel()` the transaction from inside the progress callback; I want to call `parseFile.cancel()` from everywhere. I put in the progress callback to show that, while it should stop, it doesn't.

---

**Edit** This is what I'm really trying to do. I have tried different ways but this is it.

```
ParseFile currentFile;
public void setFile(ParseFile file) {

    if (currentFile != null) {
        currentFile.cancel();
    }

    currentFile = file;
    currentFile.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
        ...
    }, new ProgressCallback() {
        ... // logs
    });
}
```

With such code and say, two big images to download, things go like:

```
//calling setFile(file1)
1
2
3
...
20
21
22
//calling setFile(file2), thus also calling file1.cancel()
1
2
23 //file1 going on!
3
24
4
25
... //things get slower and this screws up progress bars and such.
```

Comment: Have you tried to use break instead of file.cancel();?

Comment: @Want2bExpert is this the reason for the downvote? I have not tried because that's not the point. I need (and should be able to, according to the `cancel()` [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseFile.html#cancel())) to cancel the transaction by calling it on the file instance, `parseFile.cancel()`, not just from inside the callback (which makes no sense). Code in my question was a minimal example showing the issue.

Comment: I didn't down vote any answer or comment.

Comment: Note: ParseFile is not a standard API in android SDK, its from another SDK. Please mention this, its important info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like this was a real bug, now fixed. I used to stay with the `v1.9.2` release; today I updated to `v1.10.0` and everything works fine.

Comment: Did you find a bug report for this, or did it just happen to work after you updated?

Comment: I tried updating for this particular reason and it happened to work, but there was no reference to this bug in the changelog. Maybe there's a bug database somewhere.

Answer (score 10):

**TL;DR;**

The only conclusion I can draw at this point is that there is a difference in our implementations that is causing cancel to fail for you.

*EDIT*: this seems to be the case as seen in your own answer. The difference being SDK versions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32034500/2680506

**Full Answer:**

The description for the `cancel()` method:

"Cancels the current network request and **callbacks** whether it's uploading or fetching data from the server."

I was curious about this so I did a little testing of my own. I took my app, made a `ParseFile` from the bytes of an image and attempted to save it in the background.

Test 1

```
    Bitmap file = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.background);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    file.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    final ParseFile myTestFile = new ParseFile(byteArray);
    myTestFile.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback(){

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if(e == null)
            {
                Log.i(null, "Done saving.");
            }

        }

    }, new ProgressCallback(){

        @Override
        public void done(Integer progress) {
            Log.i(null, "Progress at " + progress + "%");
            if(progress > 50)
            {
                myTestFile.cancel();
            }
        }});
    //myTestFile.cancel();
```

Test 2

```
    Bitmap file = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.background);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    file.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    ParseFile myTestFile = new ParseFile(byteArray);
    myTestFile.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback(){

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if(e == null)
            {
                Log.i(null, "Done saving.");
            }

        }

    }, new ProgressCallback(){

        @Override
        public void done(Integer progress) {
            Log.i(null, "Progress at " + progress + "%");
        }});
    myTestFile.cancel();
```

The results for Test 1 were similar to what you describe, because the file is very small I only got one progress callback at 100% but then it also invoked the `SaveCallback`.

In Test 2, however, the `cancel()` method appears to function as one would expect, resulting in no logs or callbacks.

It appears that cancel fails to work *because* you are calling it from the Callback. This is consistent with the fact that you continue to see ProgressCallbacks after you originally cancel in your own tests.

**EDIT**

I just uploaded an image and tested cancel for myself, in the onCreate() method of my activity I have this code:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> newQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("TestObject");
newQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>(){
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e)
    {
        ParseFile myTestFile = objects.get(0).getParseFile("file");
        myTestFile.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e)
            {
                Log.i(null, "Download finished");
            }
        }, 
        new ProgressCallback()
        {

            @Override
            public void done(Integer percentDone)
            {
                Log.i(null, "Download at " + percentDone + "%");
            }
        });
        //myTestFile.cancel();
    }});
```

When cancel is commented, It will enter the GetDataCallback with a populated byte array. When cancel is not commented no call back will occur. Strangely enough the ProgressCallback is never called although it says it is guaranteed. However, it still appears that cancel is working for me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited my question with the code I'm really wishing to use, and `cancel()` is really not working. One difference between us might be that I'm using `getData()` while you are `save()`ing.

Comment: This is just a guess but the issue may be that you are replacing currentFile before it is cancelled, you have multiple threads going here and lots of concurrent access and weird things could be going on depending on the implementation. If currentFile is not null I would not replace it but store a new reference. I would also suggest you do some testing yourself by trying to cancel the download immediately after starting it and see if it works that way.

Comment: get versus save are both network operations using the same basic implementation so I doubt that would make a difference.

Comment: Took the test of canceling immediately after starting, and it doesn't work. In my final callback I get `bytes == null`, as stated in my question, but I still get the progress callbacks and I definitely can see my network connection get slower (by calling setFile() multiple times), so it is really downloading stuff.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Cancel still appears to be working for me.