# ParseFile cancel() not canceling upload

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm having some major problems with canceling `ParseFile` upload. This is my code inside some `ParseObject`:

```
public void cancelUpload(){
    ParseFile file = (ParseFile) get(KEY_FILE_VIDEO);
    if (file != null){
        file.cancel();
    }
}
```

The `cancel()` method is being called on the `ParseFile` object and the number of it's active `Tasks` gets reduced from 1 to 0 afterwards (I checked in debug mode). Even after that is being done it's `ProgressCallback` method continues to be called and network activity does not stop (file is constantly being uploaded).

I'm using the `Parse-1.11.0` library and have tried everything so far and am out of options at this moment, so any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I also have these in my dependencies

```
compile files('libs/Parse-1.11.0.jar')
compile files('libs/ParseCrashReporting-1.10.2.jar')
compile files('libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.10.3.jar')
compile files('libs/ParseTwitterUtils-1.10.3.jar')
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909036/parsefile-cancel-not-working-file-keeps-being-downloaded

Comment: I have checked that answer before I posted this question and unfortunately new Parse library did not solve my problem. I can confirm that the `cancel()` method is called upon the right `ParseFile` object in the middle of the uploading, but I guess there's still some bug inside the lib that does not propagate call to some final `Task` object that's doing the upload (my guess).

Comment: lib version update to v1.10.0

Comment: I initially had v1.10.2 when I noticed this. After I searched for answers, I changed my version to v1.10.0 (still had the issue). Then I changed to latest version, still the same.